# Is there a way to __scrape__ content from Facebook closed groups?

Tags: facebook

Is there a way to systematically __scrape__content from Facebook closed groups? I am member of some Facebook closed groups and i would like to monitor this groups for the occurrence of certain words - is there a possibility for this?

I have found this tool: https://mkonrad.net/projects/facebook-discussion-tk.html - but you need to manualy collect data from closed groups.

Comment: Scraping Facebook is not allowed in general (without their prior written approval). For any interaction with their systems you should only use their APIs. But access to closed groups is limited; you would need a group admin to give your app access first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook used to allow group-scraping (at least programmatically via their API), but not anymore.

The `user_group` permission, which used to allow that, is now deprecated and will be replaced by [`user_managed_groups`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/groups)